# How to search people in linkedin for multiple companies

Tags: linkedin-api, jsapi

Is that possible to search peoples for multiple companies at a time using linkedin jsapi
iam using below url for searching
its giving zero people

"/people-search:" +
            "(people:(first-name,last-name,relation-to-viewer,picture-url,public-profile-url,positions),facets:(code,buckets:(name,code,count)))" + 
            "?facets=network&facet=network,F,S&count=3&current-company=true&sort=distance&company-name=ibm,infosys,oracle";

Comment: Do you have first or second degree connections who work at ibm, infosys or oracle to start with? Your code seems correct to me.

Comment: yes i have both first degree and second degree connections who works at ibm,infosys and oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a few company IDs you need, then use the linkedin [Company ID Lookup tool](http://developer.linkedin.com/apply-getting-started#company-lookup) to get the IDs of the companies, then conduct a faceted company search as follows:

`"/people-search:" + "(people:(first-name,last-name,relation-to-viewer,picture-url,public-profile-url,positions),facets:(code,buckets:(name,code,count)))" + "?facets=network,current-company&facet=current-company,ID1,ID2,ID3&facet=network,F,S&count=3&current-company=true&sort=distance&company-name=ibm,infosys,oracle";`

Replace `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3` with the IDs of the companies you looked up with the above tool.

If you have a lot of company IDs to fetch, then conduct a company search via the API to grab the company IDs programmatically, then proceed to people search.

Comment: I used this url for getting company ids :     "/company-search:(companies:(id,name))?keywords=ibm%20oracle%20infosys".      the response i got is  {"companies": {
  "_total": 3,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": 32709,
      "name": "Qualtech Consultants"
    },
    {
      "id": 956596,
      "name": "PT Multipolar Technology"
    },
    {
      "id": 651549,
      "name": "Amstar Technologies Pvt Ltd"
    }
  ]
}}

Comment: how to get company ids of any no-of companies at a time programatically

Comment: still iam searching for the same thing,do u have any idea on this

Comment: You're searching for companies who have got ALL the keywords in their profile. Create a loop and have an individual call for each company. Alternatively try to separate the words by commas, it might help.